# Search and replace yml file using php

Tags: php, yaml

How can I edit the contents of a yaml file(config.yml) in php?

If the config.yml is:

```
1. button_1:
2.  window_num: no
3. button_2:
4.  window_num: no
```

How can I use php to edit the file to read:

```
1. button_1:
2.  window_num: yes
3. button_2:
4.  window_num: yes
```

Comment: open the file at first and read the contents. Post your efforts

Comment: Clarity and more verbose example

Answer (score 0):

I asume that you want to set `window_num: yes` for `button_2`
You can use regex to find it

```
<?php

//$file_get_contents = file_get_contents("config.yml");
$file_get_contents = " button_1:
  window_num: no
 button_2:
  window_num: no
 button_3:
  window_num: no";

echo $file_get_contents = preg_replace("/button_2:(\n?\s*)window_num: no/", "button_2:\n  window_num: yes", $file_get_contents);

?>
```

And output will be:

```
 button_1:
  window_num: no
 button_2:
  window_num: yes
 button_3:
  window_num: no
```